# Define the user with the specific password

Tags: password, shadow

I have the following users with password from /etc/shadow:

```
userA:$5$FSRFdXhqehxiiFZV$SoIvO/4Y2tvOzIi.8p1Ud6AInQ3K5XT/WqVE5Zh4GT8:18388:0:99999:7:::
userB:*:18388:0:99999:7:::
userC:$6$SJRweUUklycIq1C$ZKCPyeM9bAoTynYioSYBOmZTATXsajucfHNE3ZNfWNmql1GKdsYCTprf/aXOspBxxzlRuDEvjRlzLf7rbx.fy0:18388:0:99999:7:::
userD:$6$YgVQv3fSdlYwR$yOn6MBS5dGhMoFmPri4tsLYFzFgd0.nc8VYrSBykn/4qQwGV31NhMtoV/VJfhNqkA.FH0oP7GKxqYyK/4/0nr.:18388:0:99999:7:::
userE:$1$8HptDKnp$w32YYwwlxi9F.2JDO/gSA.:18388:0:99999:7:::
userF:$6$DWKlq62oU9k8O/z$aMNpueRgSIcILIpSMNV.gnSven6kgNbJ4QJlQM1E32snjhndk3LvfWtnR4NoiFIE4NwC7Kga7PZTlWDaxD0Gd1:18388:0:99999:7:::
userG:X014elvznJq7E:18388:0:99999:7:::
userH:$6$yhVabCDsrFv$CImM3mQGwX6Scbi/mGsl/jwKFJcdnsEq/Wjlve6ApB21ytw6/.weDMi6QkjJh3RiCO9xTBatNjwxd7vUddRS2/:18388:0:99999:7:::
```

Furthermore, I know someone useses the "EasyDiamond" as password. I want to find out who uses it. I tried to use online hashing tools to get the output hash, but unfortunately didn't get a single match. E.g. for userA tried hash the EasyDiamondFSRFdXhqehxiiFZV with SHA-256 and so on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the commands/code you used to check if a password matches the known password.

Comment: `su userA` and try "EasyDiamond" as password. Repeat for the others, probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password hashing schemes `$5$` and `$6$` are not just single SHA256 or SHA512 hashes of the password + salt. That would be way too easy to brute-force.

Instead, the hashing is iterated a configurable number of times: if the password hash does not include a `$rounds=N$` specifier, the default is 5000 iterations.

You'll find a complete description of the algorithm at: https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

OpenSSL includes a tool that can be used to calculate password hashes. For example, to manually check the password `EasyDiamond` for your `userA`, you would run:

```
openssl passwd -5 -salt FSRFdXhqehxiiFZV EasyDiamond
```

The output will be the result of the chosen password hashing algorithm (option `-5` specifies the `$5$` algorithm) with the specified salt (from the `/etc/shadow` line) and password. If it matches what is listed for `userA`in your `/etc/shadow`, you now know `userA`'s password is `EasyDiamond`.

The man page for `openssl passwd` may be a bit tricky to access, since OpenSSL usually has a separate man page for each subcommand, and this subcommand is named `passwd` which matches the regular `passwd` command. Different distributions may solve this in different ways, but a common way is to use a man section name with a suffix: in Debian/Ubuntu family of Linux distributions at least, `man 1ssl passwd` will produce a man page for the `openssl passwd` subcommand.

Or you might use `man -a passwd` to get all the possible man pages for `passwd`, including at least `/usr/bin/passwd`, `openssl passwd` and `/etc/passwd`.